# Bibliographie in latex

Tags: bibtex

I want to to write bibliography in my report, so I used `url` package :

```
\usepackage{url}

\url{https://www.clubic.com} 

\url{https://snack.expo.io }
```

but I'm not satisfied with the result (The rest of some url is not shown, what is the solution to make it lisible):
[image]

Comment: Depending on the desired linebreak points, you could give `xurl` a try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL - linebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470550/url-linebreak)

Comment: You tagged your question with the "bibtex"  tag. Did you acutally use bibtex to build your bibliography or did you create  it manually?